# How can the Microcontroller run anything else if the interrupt is really fast?

Tags: microcontroller, embedded

just a quick question. I am just confused how you are suppose to run anything else if you have a periodic interrupt going off every X amount of seconds.

If I have an ADC being interrupted at 38kHz or about ~26uS how does that leave room  to do anything? Let say I want the ADC to still be triggered every 26uS but I also want to do some math that uses the output of the ADC. Would that mean I need to create another interrupt that execute after the 26uS mark but it needs to finish before the next ADC trigger?

**This is assuming the ISR for the ADC as soon as it triggers, its completed.**

The way I think of this is a time line of deadlines

If I have an ADC that triggers every 26uS then:

0....26uS....52uS....78uS

Then the task that I want to do math in would need to finish in between the ADC triggers?

0....26uS...[Math Task]...52uS...[Math Task]....78uS

and if I want to write another task along side my math one it would be like this?

0....26uS[New Task][Math Task]....52uS..[New Task][Math Task]....78uS.

So in essence if you want to run anything else, does it need to be faster then your biggest (slowest) interrupt frequency?

Is it viable just to write your task in terms of interrupts and have it in a timeline like above or would you use the while(1) loop etc. Not sure how the while(1) loop would even work when it comes to deadlines.

Too me this seems crazy, What if I want to do audio processing? Sampling an audio signal at 44kHz and implement a digital filter by feeding my ADC values into my difference equation.

Would that mean my digital filter algorithm task:

- needs to be faster than 44kHz?
- What if its never possible for my digital filter to be that fast due
  to the arithmetic and storing past values and what not?
- Would it be not implementable then?
- How do people like Sonos have MCU doing audio processing and stuff?

**EDIT: Taking your suggestions into account I picked up 3 micro controllers for further play testing: Let me know what you guys think.
- [PIC18F25K83](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/PIC18LF25-26K83-data-sheet-40001943B.pdf) 
- [dsPIC33EP64GP502](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/70000657H.pdf)
- [STM32L432KC](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32l432kc.pdf)**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108846/discussion-on-question-by-pllsz-how-can-the-microcontroller-run-anything-else-if).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is, it can't run anything else if the interrups keep interrupting the normal execution flow. There are MCUs that run main code for one or two opcodes before accepting a new interrupt, and there are MCUs that don't exit the interrupt context at all if next interrupt is pending.

Executing and returning from interrupt takes some time too, so obviously interrupts can't happen faster than this overhead plus the actual execution time of the interrupt routine. Either you need a faster MCU then to allow more interrupts per second, or slowe interrupt rate to process them.

So yes, as you said yourself, this is crazy, and that is why audio processing is not made in ADC interrupt one sample at a time. If you are limited to this, you have the wrong MCU for audio processing. The idea of loop you mentioned is kind of towards the right way because it does not use interrupts, you have more time to fecth and calculate each sample as there is no context switch. MCUs that support DMA go further than this, the CPU can do other things while samples get written to memory without CPU. The DMA controller can be configured to give you an interrupt after a certain amount of samples have been transferred so you can process it in blocks, maybe not in interrupt context but when you have a time slot for it.

How does some commercial speaker do it? Not with a 8-bit AVR that is for sure. It might have a multi-GHz multi-core SoC with a built-in audio processor or a dedicated DSP.

Comment: Thank you for the input. So at least I am on the right track. Where I am getting confused now is don't you have to have the ADC sample at high rates? What if I want to do CD quality and sample at 44.1 kHz? I would imagine I would then use another MCU then? Have one MCU do the sampling every 44.1kHz put that in a DMA and use another MCU to retrieve that. If I were to use the MCU then I would need to be writing a task thats faster then 44.1kHz retrieving data from the DMA which I dont think would be possible?

Comment: You would not connect more AVRs together to do more. So if you want to sample, transfer and process audio, you do it with components meant for sampling, transferring and processing audio. You would choose a microcontroller with I2S audio interface and connect an audio codec with I2S interface. Internal ADCs of MCUs are in general not for sampling CD quality audio, and slow 8-bit MCUs like AVRs are not for processing CD quality audio. You don't "retrieve data from DMA", the samples are already written to MCU memory via DMA.

Comment: You choose components for sampling because it takes off the overhead from the MCU? Sorry if I sound stupid but a MCU can sample it no problem right? Its just the fact you are really left with no processing power like mention in the question right? For example I have the Atmel ATmega328P ADC setup sampling at 38kHz thats not a bad sampling time but the problem is I can't do anything as there's no task that can complete before the execution of every ADC trigger

Comment: Regards to the DMA. If the samples are already written, which is good then you would still need to send those DMA values into a difference equation still then once that's done send that value into the DAC. then if the DMA is getting values from the ADC every 38 kHz dont you need to read or use all the DMA results within 38kHz ?

Comment: With external codec you can easily achieve 192kHz resolution with two channels and 20 or more bits of resolution. Bigger MCUs or DSPs may not have any internal ADCs, or they are similar grade to AVRs - meant primarily for slow sampling of control or status data. ATmega328P ADC can sample one channel at 15 kSPS and with 10-bit resolution; that is hardly called audio these days. If you run it at 38kHz, it's beyond normal operating limits already, and you lose resolution and get increased noise.

Comment: Regards DMA, no, because you can have a 1000 byte DMA ring buffer so you can process a full buffer every 38 Hz, not single byte per 38 kHz.

Comment: Oh? I would need to research more about DMA as this is my first time being introduced to them. Are DMA already in a ring configuration? Or do you need to do that in software?

Comment: I see what you mean, but was I correct? 1. You could still use the MCU internal ADC however due to today's standard its not good. 2. Using the internal MCU at high sampling frequency leaves you no room to do anything else so using an external ADC is a better option as it takes off that over head from your MCU

Comment: Yes DMA can be used with double buffering or ring buffering or whatever the specific DMA controller happens to allow. 1) Of course you can use internal ADC as you wish. 2) If you have a slow MCU like AVR, high sampling rate leaves you no room to process it. It does not depend on if the ADC is internal or external, a slow MCU without DMA and hardware interfaces still can't do it even with an external ADC.

Comment: Oh that's really interesting, even with a external ADC? Is it because you have to retrieve the data from a SPI, or I2C/iC2 line every x Frequency?

Comment: If your AVR can't process 38000 bytes per second, it does not matter if it comes from internal ADC, SPI or I2C, it still can't process it.

Comment: I see. So the solution here is change of MCU to have a DSP that execute tasks faster than the sampling frequency of the ADC. If thats possible theres no need for an external ADC unless you want better sampling quality it looks like

Comment: CD quality audio uses TWO channels, and each channel is 16 bits at 44.1kHz. So that is 44100 * 16 * 2 = 1411200 bits per second or 176400 bytes per second of data that has to be transported over the bus or DMA channel or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the CPU time required to process the ADC samples must be less than the time it takes to collect the samples.  Otherwise the CPU will lose/drop samples because it is too busy processing previous samples.

However, the CPU does not typically retrieve each sample from the ADC.  Typically the DMA controller is configured to handle the ADC interrupt and copy the sample from the ADC controller to RAM without CPU involvement.  This way the CPU is free from the work of copying individual samples.

And signal processing algorithms do not typically operate on a single sample at a time.  Rather, signal processing is performed on batches of samples so that the algorithm can be executed more efficiently.  The DMA controller is configured to interrupt the CPU when a fixed-size batch of samples has been read from the ADC.  Then the CPU processes the entire batch of samples.  This way the CPU gets interrupted only every 512 samples (or whatever the batch-size is).

Finally, the DMA controller is typically setup to double buffer the ADC samples.  This means that the DMA fills one buffer and interrupts the CPU to perform signal processing.  Then while the CPU is working on that first buffer, the DMA receives new samples into a second buffer so as to not corrupt the first buffer while the CPU is operating on it.  The CPU needs to complete the signal processing operations on the first buffer before the ADC/DMA fill the second buffer.  When the second buffer is full the DMA controller interrupts the CPU again and the CPU processes the second buffer.  The DMA controller reverts to filling the first buffer because the CPU is done with it.  The buffers ping-pong back and forth, first filled by the DMA controller, and then processed by the CPU.  DMA controllers often have two interrupt sources for half-buffer and full-buffer filled to support this ping-pong technique.

The CPU must be able to complete the signal processing on a batch of samples in the time it takes to collect a batch.  The CPU is interrupted by the DMA controller at a rate of the ADC sample-rate times the batch-size, it is not interrupted every sample.  If the CPU cannot perform all the operations required to process a batch of samples in the time it takes to collect them, then you need another form of relief such as a faster CPU clock speed, a CPU with faster built-in DSP instructions, a co-processor to offload some work to, or requirements relief allowing for a simpler signal processing algorithm or allowing samples to be dropped.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! This does make a lot of sense. So essentially after reading this I am starting to think using interrupts is not a good idea as it will use the processor time. Can the ADC and DMA interact with each other with zero CPU involvement? If so thats the move then, thats the way I would do it.

Comment: Is there a difference between DMA and SRAM/RAM? for example how do I find out if a MCU ha the DMA feature? Can it work with this http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39582C.pdf

Comment: Using interrupts based on a timer with a *dedicated* processor to collect the samples has a major advantage; in a DSP (sampled data) world it is *very* important that the sampling rate is constant. http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/AN-756.pdf?doc=AN-1457.pdf

Comment: After the CPU configures the ADC and DMA appropriately, yes, the ADC and DMA interact with zero CPU involvement.  The DMA controller is a CPU peripheral in the same way that the ADC controller, I2C controller, or SPI controllers are CPU peripherals.  See the microcontroller datasheet for the available peripherals.